# output of numpy.where(condition) is not an array, but a tuple of arrays: why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am experimenting with the `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])` function.
From the [numpy documentation,](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) I learn that if you give just one array as input, it should return the indices where the array is non-zero (i.e. "True"):

> If only condition is given, return the tuple condition.nonzero(), the
>   indices where condition is True.

But if try it, it returns me a *tuple* of two elements, where the first is the wanted list of indices, and the second is a null element:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> np.where(array>4)
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),) # notice the comma before the last parenthesis
```

so the question is: why? what is the purpose of this behaviour? in what situation this is useful?
Indeed, to get the wanted list of indices I have to add the indexing, as in `np.where(array>4)[0]`, which seems... "ugly".

---

ADDENDUM

I understand (from some answers) that it is actually a tuple of just one element. Still I don't understand why to give the output in this way. To illustrate how this is not ideal, consider the following error (which motivated my question in the first place):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> pippo = np.where(array>4)
>>> pippo + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

so that you need to do some indexing to access the actual array of indices:

```
>>> pippo[0] + 1
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: How about `np.argwhere`?

Comment: What you want is `np.flatnonzero`, which does `a.ravel().nonzero()[0]`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Python `(1)` means just `1`.  `()` can be freely added to group numbers and expressions for human readability (e.g. `(1+3)*3` v `(1+3,)*3`).  Thus to denote a 1 element tuple it uses `(1,)` (and requires you to use it as well).

Thus

```
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),)
```

is a one element tuple, that element being an array.

If you applied `where` to a 2d array, the result would be a 2 element tuple.

The result of `where` is such that it can be plugged directly into an indexing slot, e.g.

```
a[where(a>0)]
a[a>0]
```

should return the same things

as would

```
I,J = where(a>0)   # a is 2d
a[I,J]
a[(I,J)]
```

Or with your example:

```
In [278]: a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
In [279]: np.where(a>4)
Out[279]: (array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32),)  # tuple

In [280]: a[np.where(a>4)]
Out[280]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [281]: I=np.where(a>4)
In [282]: I
Out[282]: (array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32),)
In [283]: a[I]
Out[283]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [286]: i, = np.where(a>4)   # note the , on LHS
In [287]: i
Out[287]: array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32)  # not tuple
In [288]: a[i]
Out[288]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [289]: a[(i,)]
Out[289]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

======================

`np.flatnonzero` shows the correct way of returning just one array, regardless of the dimensions of the input array.

```
In [299]: np.flatnonzero(a>4)
Out[299]: array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32)
In [300]: np.flatnonzero(a>4)+10
Out[300]: array([14, 15, 16, 17, 18], dtype=int32)
```

It's doc says:

> This is equivalent to a.ravel().nonzero()[0]

In fact that is literally what the function does.

By flattening `a` removes the question of what to do with multiple dimensions.  And then it takes the response out of the tuple, giving you a plain array. With flattening it doesn't have make a special case for 1d arrays.

===========================

@Divakar suggests `np.argwhere`:

```
In [303]: np.argwhere(a>4)
Out[303]: 
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8]], dtype=int32)
```

which does `np.transpose(np.where(a>4))`

Or if you don't like the column vector, you could transpose it again

```
In [307]: np.argwhere(a>4).T
Out[307]: array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

except now it is a 1xn array.

We could just as well have wrapped `where` in `array`:

```
In [311]: np.array(np.where(a>4))
Out[311]: array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

Lots of ways of taking an array out the `where` tuple (`[0]`, `i,=`, `transpose`, `array`, etc).

Comment: hi @hpaulj, thank you for your answer. I understand, it is a tuple of 1 element. Still, you need the indexing to access the actual array, and I don't understand why, i.e. why to give the output in that way... 
See the addendum in the edited question.

Comment: The goal is consistency across all arrays.  `np.flatnonzero` shows the correct way returning an array instead of a tuple.

Comment: So, why [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does it say "Returns: out : ndarray  An array with elements..."  That's what confused me.

Comment: @Bill, that `out` is for the 3 parameter use.  On SO we often use it with only a condition parameter.  The docs now recommend using `np.nonzero` for that purpose.

Comment: Ah yes, Thank you @hpaulj.  Now I see the note near the top of the page which says "The rest of this documentation covers only the case where all three arguments are provided."

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: `np.where` is designed to have consistent output regardless of the dimension of the array.

A two-dimensional array has two indices, so the result of `np.where` is a length-2 tuple containing the relevant indices. This generalizes to a length-3 tuple for 3-dimensions, a length-4 tuple for 4 dimensions, or a length-N tuple for N dimensions. By this rule, it is clear that in 1 dimension, the result should be a length-1 tuple.

Comment: I don't understand why not a n-d array whose nth axis corresponds to the nth dimension? Can different elements of the tuple be of different lengths?

Comment: Indexing with arrays has different semantics than indexing with tuples. If the result were an ndarray rather than a tuple, `x[np.where(x == 0)]` would not return the zero elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`np.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) function. In your case:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> pippo = np.asarray(np.where(array>4))
>>> pippo + 1
array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Why is `np.asarray()` used instead of `np.array()`?