# One liner to get an array of positions form NUMPY array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array named histarr with the shape 1, 13

```
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint32)
```

I want to get an array that gives me positions where 1's are, hence I used np.where

```
where_are_ones_arr = np.where(histarr == 1)
```

The output is:

```
(array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

I was confused for a while but than I checked the type and I realized that `where_are_ones_arr` is not an array but it is actually a tuple, so if I wanted to get an array I used:

```
where_are_ones_arr[0]
```

Result:

```
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
```

Now that is all fine but I found it unbelievable that I cannot get that in one line, so I looked around and tried:

```
where_are_ones_give_me_only_array = histarr[np.where(histarr == 1)]
```

But it spits out:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint32)
```

Which is not what I want and what I can explain?
What is it that I do not get?

Comment: `np.where(histarr == 1)[0]` or `np.flatnonzero(histarr == 1)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [output of numpy.where(condition) is not an array, but a tuple of arrays: why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747908/output-of-numpy-wherecondition-is-not-an-array-but-a-tuple-of-arrays-why)

Comment: Thanks Divakar, that works.
@StupidWolf I read that answer and an answer from paulj line 280 where he uses technique that I tried to reproduce in my question does not work for me.

Comment: I still do not get how I get the result that I get in my question.

Comment: Also: `np.where()` with only one argument is just calling under the hood just `np.nonzero()`, so calling `np.nonzero()` directly should be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it in one line:

```
np.where(histarr == 1)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks that works NOW magically. I tried that before and got some error that I can not reproduce anymore.