# Python np.where has odd brackets

Tags: numpy

I was wondering if there was some way in python to get rid of these extra brackets. example:

```
In [211]: a = np.array([1,3,4,6])

In [221]: np.where(a > 1)
Out[221]: (array([1, 2, 3]),)

In [222]: len(np.where(a > 1))
Out[222]: 1

In [223]: len(np.where(a > 1)[0])
Out[223]: 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [output of numpy.where(condition) is not an array, but a tuple of arrays: why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747908/output-of-numpy-wherecondition-is-not-an-array-but-a-tuple-of-arrays-why)

Comment: `(foobar, )` is a one element tuple.  `where` produces a tuple of arrays, one per dimension.

Comment: What is wrong with using `np.where(a > 1)[0]`?